When was the concept of the Emotion Lord explained to the audience?
When - in Pendleton Ward's science fiction franchise Bravest Warriors - was the concept of the Emotion Lord explained or exposited to the audience, either in the comic or animated productions?
For example, in which webisode\episode or comic book issue was it communicated to the audience details such as what qualities an Emotion Lord possessed, how one might be identified, or what powers they possessed.
As opposed to an Emotion Lord appearing and the main characters being aware of them, but not performing any actions or producing any dialogue which passed on expository information to the audience.

https://bravestwarriors.fandom.com/wiki/Emotion_Lord

That's a fan wiki, maybe you could extract the information out of it and write it in the form of an answer?

@ValorumThat wiki article doesn't actually say where the concept of an emotion lord was exposited to the audience. It just has a couple of examples where they did things in specific episodes.

I haven't seen the show, so I'm not overkeen. Maybe you could do the honours and self-answer?

@Valorum, the answer isn't in the wiki, and I can't self answer as I don't know the answer. The wiki is contradictory and only includes instances of specific things happening or characters appearing, there isn't anything about exposition in it.
